# Missing signature error while sending transaction from anchor

Tags: anchor, web3.js

I'm trying to call my Anchor contract with the following code:

```
 async function createCounter(){
        const provider = getProvider();
        const baseAccount = web3.Keypair.generate();
        if(!provider){
            throw ("Provider is null")
        }
        const a = JSON.stringify(idl);
        const b = JSON.parse(a);

        console.log(idl.metadata.address)
        const program = new Program(b,idl.metadata.address,provider);
        
        try {

            await program.rpc.initialize({
                accounts: {
                    myAccount:baseAccount.publicKey,
                    user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                    systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                    
                },
                signers: [baseAccount],
            })
            const account = await program.account.myAccount.fetch(baseAccount.publicKey);

            console.log("account: ",account)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Transaction error: ",error);
        }
    }
```

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub my_account: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

But I get this error when calling the function createCounter:

```
Missing signature for public key [`BT8gQAPWXdebC6rD6dZsookJg2iiTgEvKEyj8NxkwbJS`].
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the `user` account is declared as a signer, but you're not signing with it (which is what the error message is saying too):

```
await program.rpc.initialize({
                accounts: {
                    myAccount:baseAccount.publicKey,
                    user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                    systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                    
                },
                signers: [baseAccount],
            })
```

To fix this either put `baseAccount` in the `user` field of the accounts here (easier), or sign using the provider wallet.

Note that for the provider wallet you'll need to build the actual transaction object and either use the `signTransaction` method  and then send or use the `sendAndConfirm` on the provider directly.

Comment: can i get an example?

Comment: Sure, for the first case just do:



`await program.rpc.initialize({
                accounts: {
                    myAccount:baseAccount.publicKey,
                    user: baseAccount.publicKey,
                    systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                    
                },
                signers: [baseAccount],
            })`

and it should work (sorry for the terrible comment formatting :) )

Comment: It didn't work for the use case

Comment: Could you provide a bit more details about your requirements in that case? From your question you just asked how to get rid of the specific error, otherwise anyone answering is just guessing